# How to implement preference fragment into a exisiting fragment?

Tags: android, fragment, preferencefragment

I am trying to load a already designed preferenceFragment(MainSetting fragment) into a existing fragment(setting fragment), I using the follow commands to load fragment:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content,new MainSettingsFragment ()).commit();
```

But the code says that:

```
Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'com.example.***.myapplication.SettingFragment.MainSettingsFragment', required: 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment'
```

Is there any problems about package or import? or my load method is totally wrong?   Here is my main code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class SettingFragment extends Fragment {


public SettingFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content,new 
MainSettingsFragment ()).commit();
 }

public static class MainSettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}

}
```

**Update**

I solved my problem by downloading android.support.v4 jar, It looks fine by combining those two fragment, But when I running my app, It shows another following issues

```
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class selector
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class selector
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.selector" on path: DexPathList
```

I checked my code multiple times, I still do not know why I get this error, Is that means I should add a selector in my preferenceFragment xml file?

Lastly, here I list the preferenceFragment layout file

**preferences.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<PreferenceCategory
    android:key="user_category"
    android:title="Sensor Setting"
    >

    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="acc_setting"
        android:summary="Movement information"
        android:title="Acceleration" />
    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="acc1_setting"
        android:summary="Acceleration without gravity"
        android:title="Linear Acceleration" />
    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="gyro_setting"
        android:summary="Angle information"
        android:title="Gyroscope" />
    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="magne_setting"
        android:summary="Magnetic information"
        android:title="Magnetic" />
    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="orien_setting"
        android:summary="Orientation information"
        android:title="Orientation" />
    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="rota_setting"
        android:summary="Rotation information"
        android:title="Rotation" />

</PreferenceCategory>

<PreferenceCategory
    android:key="visua_category"
    android:title="Visualization"
    >

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="falsee"
        android:key="visual_data"
        android:summary="Real-time visualize sensor data"
        android:title="Visualizing Sensor Information" />

</PreferenceCategory>
```

Comment: MainSettingsFragment must extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment also

Comment: post MainSettingsFragment instead of SettingFragment

Answer (score 0):

I think you should extend import `android.support.v4.preference.PreferenceFragment` instead of `import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;`

Comment: No. He's `MainSettingsFragment` should extend  Fragment. That all.